# python - convert docx to HTML including Fonts and Fonts Size

Tags: python, xml-parsing, python-docx, mammoth

I'm trying to convert a file from **Docx** to **HTML** with font family, fonts size and colors in Python, I tried couple of solutions i.e [Python docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/), [docx2html](https://pypi.org/project/docx2html/), [Python Mammoth](https://github.com/mwilliamson/python-mammoth).

but none of the packages works for me. these packages are converting to HTML, but many things related to styles i.e fonts, size, and colors are skipped.

I tried to open and read docx files using Python `zipfile` and get XML of word file, I got all the docx information in XML, so now I'm thinking of parsing XML to HTML in Python, Maybe I can find any parser for this purpose.

Here's the snippet of code that I tried with [Python docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/) but I'm getting `None` values here.

```py
d = Document('1.docx')
d_styles = d.styles
for key in d_styles:
    print(f'{key} : {d_styles[key]}')
```

for XML using `zipfile` here's my code snippet.

```py
docx = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
content = docx.read('word/document.xml').decode('utf-8')
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.